# Can't create simple DLL example

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I followed [microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) and stumbled at moment when DLL project should compile like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MathLibrary, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------  
1>  stdafx.cpp  
1>  dllmain.cpp  
1>  MathLibrary.cpp  
1>     Creating library c:\users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MathLibraryAndClient\Debug\MathLibrary.lib and object c:\users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MathLibraryAndClient\Debug\MathLibrary.exp  
1>  MathLibrary.vcxproj -> c:\users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\MathLibraryAndClient\Debug\MathLibrary.dll  
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

But i compiling my DLL project successfully but i have less in output. And in a result my main app can't compile because "there is no .lib file of your DLL" as compiler said.

Output of DLL project looks like this:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: testDLL, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>stdafx.cpp
1>dllmain.cpp
1>someClass.cpp
1>testDLL.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>testDLL.vcxproj -> D:\stud\VStest\testDLL\Debug\testDLL.dll
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My output obviously lacks "Creating library" part. I don't understand what's wrong, my VS is 2017.

P.S. what MS mean by that comment in CPP file?

```
// Compile by using: cl /EHsc /DMATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS /LD MathLibrary.cpp
```

Comment: If you don't export symbols you don't get an import library. My guess is you did not do the preprocessor definition step.

Comment: @drescherjm Well, i add to .h file preprocessor stuff as they did, nothing changed.
One thing i noticed which i dont have, they have such comment in CPP file of class:
// Compile by using: cl /EHsc /DMATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS /LD MathLibrary.cpp 
i'm completely ignorant about what said in here, i don't even get how to google it. What they want me to do?

Comment: So my guess was correct you skipped the preprocessor definition step.  defining `MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS` is essential to make the import library. Without that it will not work since the dll will not export any symbols. In your project settings in Visual Studio look under `c++` for preprocessor definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DLL project goto

**Project Settings -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor definitions**

And add

**MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS** definition

So `MATHLIBRARY_API` macros

```
#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif
```

will be solved to `__declspec(dllexport)`. This will instruct compiler/linker to export function marked with this attribute into DLL export section as well as into import library (if you have the project setting to [create import library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584041/how-do-i-build-an-import-library-lib-and-a-dll-in-visual-c) ).

As well as, you can implement your class as following:

```
namespace MathLibrary  
{  
    // This class is exported from the MathLibrary.dll  
    class MATHLIBRARY_API Functions  
    {  
    public:  
        // Returns a + b  
        static double Add(double a, double b);  

        // Returns a * b  
        static double Multiply(double a, double b);  

        // Returns a + (a * b)  
        static double AddMultiply(double a, double b);  
    };  
}
```

Alternatively you can use [def files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files) instead of __declspec

Comment: Tnx! But one more crucial thing was strange addition of MATHLIBRARY_API at the beginning of functions declarations. Have no clue what is that, but after i add that, i compile properly as it should. But now it gives me couple errors(not DLL project, project of my main test program which should use that DLL) - https://image.ibb.co/jbSBse/dllfuck.jpg

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886670/add-a-dependency-reference-to-your-own-dll-project-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Well, i've already add reference to main project, and when i went to project dependencies(after your link) there already was chosen in check-box my dll project(project: main, and check-box for my .dll proj). But i glanced in build order, first stays main project, and second dll, i dont know how to swap them...

Comment: I rly can't understand why this error comes to my main project, in build order first build .dll project, then main.
What the hell this pop-up error if i press "start debugging" https://image.ibb.co/gP7uJU/fcngmsvs.jpg

Comment: My problem was object creation issue. I made my test functions in .dll project static so no object need to create and now it all work!