# Trouble using DLL

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I am completely new to C#. I am trying to run a C# code that uses a DLL written in C++. The DLL file is,

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl analysis(double* values, int len)
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<int> ind(values, values + len);
    int n = ind.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << ind[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

And the C# code,

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test_run
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("Test.dll")]
        public static extern void analysis([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] double[] values, int len);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<double> lst = new List<double>();
            lst.Add(1.2);
            lst.Add(2.3);
            lst.Add(3.4);

            analysis(lst.ToArray(), lst.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Both files compile individually. But when I run the program it raises exception "Unable to load DLL "Test.dll" or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)". They are both in same solution and the C# project has the DLL added.

Comment: Have you added the reference to your DLL in your project? If not this might help. [Adding dependencies in your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886670/add-a-dependency-reference-to-your-own-dll-project-in-visual-studio-2013/31886671)

Comment: Your Test.dll has to be in the same folder as your C# executable. You can do that by adding the dll as an item to the project or with a postbuild action.

Comment: Side note: `lst.ToArray()` means that it is working on a copy, so you will never see the results

Comment: I have the dll project referenced. The dependency setup is also done. The solution looks like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/F0Azy3d).

Comment: @Charlieface, I am aware of that. This is just a test run to learn DLL import. The results in the actual project will be output to file.

Comment: Thank you everyone. @Timo, thank you for the tip. Apparently, I needed to put the entire filepath. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't sufficient to add the DLL to the project, but you need to make sure the DLL file is actually copied over to the output directory of the Executable.

If you added the DLL file in your C# project, you can set the "Build Action" => "None", and "Copy to Output Directory" => "Copy if newer".  That should make sure your dll is in the right place.

[image]